# How to force open a universal link in the browser on Android, even if my app handles the intent

Tags: android

In my Android app, I configured Universal links.

In the Manifest:

```
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="domain.tld" />
      </intent-filter>
```

This is working properly and links like `https://domain.tld/something` are opening the app.

Now I would like to have a button to open a link to my website inside the user's browser, for example `https://domain.tld/marketing_page`.

When I create a `android.intent.action.VIEW` intent to open this URL, this opens my app at it is matching my intent.

Are there any intent categories or tags to prevent opening my app and open the URL in a real browser?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it seems like a conflicting behavior for basically the same links. You can try to explicitly [limit](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking) your responsibilities between deeplinks and web-browsing by using data and pathPrefix in it. All other links won't be accepted by app as matching ones and the system will open a browser.

```
 <data android:scheme="http"
     android:host="domain.tld"
     android:pathPrefix="/something" />
```

It would make sense to just create some kind of deeplink prefixes that come from you website. You app will process the higher part, for example /deeplink, and then you could parse if it's a /deeplink/a, or /deeplink/b and so on.